# SQL query LEFT JOIN causes two outputs but should only be one

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble in my table structure and query in the result what I wanted is that it would only output one result which is the first one. What changes in my table structures should I make? Because it only returns the same output but different prf_id.

So here is the situation. tbl_prf is for the request of personnel. tbl_job_plist is for the jobs posted, and tbl_applicant is for applicant. When I add a entry in tbl_prf it would choose from the tbl_job_plist of its reference example is the entry. Then when I'm trying to view the applicant it is needed to show the tbl_prf ID and ID of the tbl_job_plist selected. So that is how I came up with that code. What happens when I view an applicant It would select both of the tbl_prf entries causing two outputs with the same applicant.

What I'm trying to do is get applicants with ap_status of 1. As you can see I only have one applicant so I'm expecting only one result. What happens is the applicant name keeps on showing on the result if the prf_job_post_ref and jplist_id are equal. How do I prevent it?
tbl_prf

```
prf_id       | prf_job_post_ref |           
------------------------------------       
1            |        1         |
3            |        1         |
```

tbl_job_plist

```
jplist_id    | jplist_position     |
------------------------------------
1            |        Crew         |
```

tbl_applicant

```
ap_id        | ap_position_applied | ap_status | ap_name |
----------------------------------------------------------
1            |        1            |     1     |   Kurt  |
```

QUERY

```
    SELECT
    tbl_applicant.ap_id, 
    tbl_applicant.ap_name,
    tbl_job_plist.jplist_id, 
    tbl_prf.prf_id 
    FROM tbl_applicant 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_job_plist ON tbl_applicant.ap_position_applied = tbl_job_plist.jplist_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref 
    WHERE ap_status = 1
```

Result

```
ap_id        | jplist_id           | prf_id     | ap_name |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            |        1            |     1      |   Kurt  |
1            |        1            |     3      |   Kurt  |
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The SQL is correct and you will get 2 rows back, nothing wrong there. What does your data mean and what are you trying to get it to tell you?

Comment: What I want is that only one result would appear, either of the two. I know that my query is wrong if I want to achieve that result. So what would you suggest I need to do to correct it?

Comment: to limit number of rows u can use rowcount =1 . But still I am not clear what u want to achieve. If you knw the table possibly can give u duplicates try to remove duplicates before u put join.

Comment: @Avi I've added the situation that I'm in to achieve the record that stated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment of wanting exactly one row and not caring which, you can use `TOP`, like this...

```
SELECT TOP 1
    tbl_applicant.ap_id, 
    tbl_job_plist.jplist_id, 
    tbl_prf.prf_id 
    FROM tbl_applicant 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_job_plist ON tbl_applicant.ap_position_applied = tbl_job_plist.jplist_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref 
    WHERE ap_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which of those two tows you want to return, you would either use a MAX or MIN subquery. So after

`LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref`

you could put

```
and tbl_prf.prf_id =(select max(pe.prf_id) from tbl_prf pe where pe.prf_job_post_ref= tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref )
```

This would return the row with the value of 3 in your example.